# Is there a way to define fields dynamically, but not as the last field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-translated-fields

I have a `ModelForm` with Django 2.1, and I moved a few fields to another model. Calling `make_migrations` causes an error because these fields don't exist in the current model. I added some of the fields to the form, but one of the fields is a `TranslatedField` (from [django-translated-fields](https://github.com/matthiask/django-translated-fields/)) and therefore there are currently 2 fields, and in the future there might be more, depending on the number of languages. The name of the field is city, and currently I get an error message "`Unknown field(s) (city_en, city_he) specified for SiteProfile`" (because I'm using 2 languages - "en" and "he") - but I want to create all the fields dynamically with a for loop over the languages we use in the project. Can I override (and is it a good programming method) the `__new__` method or is there another way? I prefer not to hard-code the specific field names (`city_en` and `city_he`) because they may change in the future, depending on how many languages we use.

You can see my current [commit](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/commit/f2c9b306c1a5f7a41b19d605f7871c07a67af93f) (not working) on GitHub.

And the current [code](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/uri_move_fields_to_speedy_net_2019-07-10_b/speedy/match/accounts/forms.py) of this branch.

I would like to know what is the best programming method to define a dynamic list of fields (which are all identical, and only one of them will be used, the other are removed in the `__init__` method) in a ModelForm where the fields are saved in another model (there are 2 models but only one form).

I still didn't commit the migrations because of this error when running make_migrations.

(I defined a command `make_migrations` which only does `makemigrations`)

The form (with my trying to override `__new__`):

```
class SpeedyMatchProfileBaseForm(DeleteUnneededFieldsMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    user_fields = (
        'diet',
        'smoking_status',
        'marital_status',
        *(to_attribute(name='city', language_code=language_code) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES),
    )
    validators = {
        'height': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_height],
        'diet': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_diet],
        'smoking_status': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_smoking_status],
        'marital_status': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_marital_status],
        **{to_attribute(name='profile_description', language_code=language_code): [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_profile_description] for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
        **{to_attribute(name='city', language_code=language_code): [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_city] for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
        **{to_attribute(name='children', language_code=language_code): [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_children] for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
        **{to_attribute(name='more_children', language_code=language_code): [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_more_children] for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
        **{to_attribute(name='match_description', language_code=language_code): [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_match_description] for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
        'gender_to_match': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_gender_to_match],
        'min_age_match': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_min_age_match],
        'max_age_match': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_max_age_match],
        'diet_match': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_diet_match],
        'smoking_status_match': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_smoking_status_match],
        'marital_status_match': [speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_marital_status_match],
    }
    # ~~~~ TODO: diet choices depend on the current user's gender. Also same for smoking status and marital status.
    diet = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.DIET_VALID_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=_('My diet'))
    smoking_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.SMOKING_STATUS_VALID_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=_('My smoking status'))
    marital_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.MARITAL_STATUS_VALID_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=_('My marital status'))
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=CustomPhotoWidget, label=_('Add profile picture'))

    class Meta:
        model = SpeedyMatchSiteProfile
        fields = (
            'photo',
            *(to_attribute(name='profile_description', language_code=language_code) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES),
            *(to_attribute(name='city', language_code=language_code) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES),
            'height',
            *(to_attribute(name='children', language_code=language_code) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES),
            *(to_attribute(name='more_children', language_code=language_code) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES),
            'diet',
            'smoking_status',
            'marital_status',
            'gender_to_match',
            *(to_attribute(name='match_description', language_code=language_code) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES),
            'min_age_match',
            'max_age_match',
            'diet_match',
            'smoking_status_match',
            'marital_status_match',
        )
        widgets = {
            'smoking_status': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'marital_status': forms.RadioSelect(),
            **{to_attribute(name='profile_description', language_code=language_code): forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 25}) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
            **{to_attribute(name='city', language_code=language_code): forms.TextInput() for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
            **{to_attribute(name='children', language_code=language_code): forms.TextInput() for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
            **{to_attribute(name='more_children', language_code=language_code): forms.TextInput() for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
            **{to_attribute(name='match_description', language_code=language_code): forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 25}) for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES},
            'diet_match': CustomJsonWidget(choices=User.DIET_VALID_CHOICES),
            'smoking_status_match': CustomJsonWidget(choices=User.SMOKING_STATUS_VALID_CHOICES),
            'marital_status_match': CustomJsonWidget(choices=User.MARITAL_STATUS_VALID_CHOICES),
        }

    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for language_code, language_name in django_settings.LANGUAGES:
            setattr(cls, to_attribute(name='city', language_code=language_code), forms.CharField(label=_('city or locality'), max_length=120))
        return super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.step = kwargs.pop('step', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.delete_unneeded_fields()
        if ('gender_to_match' in self.fields):
            self.fields['gender_to_match'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=User.GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
        if ('photo' in self.fields):
            self.fields['photo'].widget.attrs['user'] = self.instance.user
        if ('diet' in self.fields):
            update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['diet'], choices=self.instance.user.get_diet_choices())
            self.fields['diet'].initial = self.instance.user.diet
        if ('smoking_status' in self.fields):
            update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['smoking_status'], choices=self.instance.user.get_smoking_status_choices())
            self.fields['smoking_status'].initial = self.instance.user.smoking_status
        if ('marital_status' in self.fields):
            update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['marital_status'], choices=self.instance.user.get_marital_status_choices())
            self.fields['marital_status'].initial = self.instance.user.marital_status
        if ('diet_match' in self.fields):
            update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['diet_match'], choices=self.instance.get_diet_match_choices())
        if ('smoking_status_match' in self.fields):
            update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['smoking_status_match'], choices=self.instance.get_smoking_status_match_choices())
        if ('marital_status_match' in self.fields):
            update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['marital_status_match'], choices=self.instance.get_marital_status_match_choices())
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            if (field_name in self.validators):
                field.validators.extend(self.validators[field_name])
                field.required = True
```

**Update 1:** I'm thinking about defining these fields in the `__init__` method while removing them from the `fields` in `class Meta`, but is it a good approach? To define fields which are not in the list of `fields`?

Django [warns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) against defining fields not explicitly.

> It is strongly recommended that you explicitly set all fields that
>   should be edited in the form using the fields attribute. Failure to do
>   so can easily lead to security problems when a form unexpectedly
>   allows a user to set certain fields, especially when new fields are
>   added to a model. Depending on how the form is rendered, the problem
>   may not even be visible on the web page.
>
> The alternative approach would be to include all fields automatically,
>   or blacklist only some. This fundamental approach is known to be much
>   less secure and has led to serious exploits on major websites (e.g.
>   GitHub).

I want to know if there is a solution without hard-coding the languages. Currently I hard-coded the languages:

```
_city = forms.CharField(label=_('City or locality'), max_length=120, error_messages={'required': _("Please write where you live.")})
city_en = _city
city_he = _city
```

https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/match/accounts/forms.py#L64-L66

**Update 2:** I found out that I can add this field dynamically by adding this line in the `__init__` method of the form:

```
# Create the localized city field dynamically.
self.fields[to_attribute(name='city')] = forms.CharField(label=_('City or locality'), max_length=120, error_messages={'required': _("Please write where you live.")})
```

And then removing it from the fields list in `class Meta` and from the hard-coded definition in the form itself. But, the field is created as the last field in the form and I want it to be in the middle. Is there a way to add this field in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update 2:** ... But, the field is created as the last field in the form and I want it to be in the middle. Is there a way to add this field in the middle?

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#notes-on-field-ordering:

> If `field_order` is a list of field names, the fields are ordered as specified by the list and remaining fields are appended according to the default order. ...
>
> You may rearrange the fields any time using `order_fields()` with a list of field names as in `field_order`.

```py
class SpeedyMatchProfileBaseForm(DeleteUnneededFieldsMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

        # Create the localized city field dynamically.
        self.fields[to_attribute('city')] = forms.CharField(label=_('City or locality'), max_length=120, error_messages={'required': _("Please write where you live.")})

        # Rearrange the fields.
        # self.order_fields((
        #     'photo',
        #     to_attribute('profile_description'),
        #     to_attribute('city')),
        #     # Remaining fields are appended according to the default order.
        # )
        self.order_fields(field_order=self.get_fields())
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! You got my bounty. But I already had a function which returns the fields in correct order, so I only had to call `self.order_fields(field_order=self.get_fields())`, as you can see in https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/match/accounts/forms.py#L200-L201. Do you want to update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but I have a survey application where different users want different information on the background information form.  I provide it via a json  file. So within the form I have

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.curr_context = kwargs.pop('context', None)
    self.filename = self.get_json_filename()
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if os.path.isfile(self.filename) :
        rows = []
        selected_fields = []
        fieldsets = json.load(open(self.filename))
        for fieldset in fieldsets:
            fields = []
            for field in fieldset['fields']:
                if 'field' in field: selected_fields.append(field['field'])
                if 'widget_type' in field:
                    if field['widget_type'] == 'Select': self.fields[field['field']].widget = forms.Select()
                if "choices" in field:
                    choices = []
                    for choice in field['choices']:
                        choices.append((choice['key'],choice['value']))
                    self.fields[field['field']].widget.choices = choices    
                    self.fields[field['field']].choices = choices
                    self.initial[field['field']] = getattr(self.instance, field['field'])
                if 'help' in field:
                    self.fields[field['field']].help_text = field['help']
                if 'html' in field:
                    fields.append(HTML(field['html']))
                if 'divs' in field:
                    fields.append(Field(field['field'], css_class="enabler"))
                    for div in field['divs']:
                        fields.append(Div(Field(div['field'], css_class=div["css"]),*div['div'], css_class="dependent"))
                        selected_fields.append(div['field'])
                        for item in div['div'] : selected_fields.append(item)
                elif 'div' in field:
                    fields.append(Field(field['field'], css_class="enabler"))
                    fields.append(Div(*field['div'], css_class="dependent"))
                    for f in field['div']:
                        selected_fields.append(f)
                else:
                    if 'field' in field: fields.append(field['field'])

            rows.append(Fieldset(fieldset['fieldset'], *fields))
```

My json file will look something like:

```
[{
    "fieldset" : "Basic Information",
    "fields" : [
        {
            "field" : "form_filler",
            "div" : ["form_filler_other"]
        },{
            "field" : "child_dob"
        },{
            "field" : "age"
        },{
            "field" : "sex"
        },{
            "field" : "country", 
            "div" : ["zip_code"]
        },{
            "field" : "birth_order"
        }, {
            "field" : "multi_birth_boolean",
            "div" : ["multi_birth"]
        }, {
            "field" : "birth_weight_kg",
            "choices" : [
                {
                    "key" : "",
                    "value" : "--------"
                },{ 
                    "key" : "1.0",
                    "value" : "Henry 1"
                },{ 
                    "key" : "2.0",
                    "value" : "Weight 2"
                },{ 
                    "key" : "3.0",
                    "value" : "Weight 3"
                },{ 
                    "key" : "4.0",
                    "value" : "Weight 4"
                }
            ],
            "widget_type" :  "Select"
        }, {
            "field" : "born_on_due_date", 
            "div" : ["early_or_late", "due_date_diff"]
        }

    ]
}, { ...
}]
```

The `field` key is an input field as are the items within the `div` list.  In this case when the field is selected (BooleanField) the fields within the `div` list must be completed which I do through the clean method.

All my fields are specified within the model so you can only pick and choose which fields to use

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to understand what exactly you have problem with. It would be really helpful if you could answer the questions i ask below.

> I'm moving a few fields to another model

What fields? From which model? To which model?
I presume that you are moving `city` field from `User` model to `SiteProfile`.

> Calling `make_migrations` causes an error because these fields don't
>   exist in the current model

What error? What is `current model` referring to? `SiteProfile`?  It should be perfectly doable to move field from one model to another.

I've looked around your repository. Especially branches where you tried to migrate from `django-modeltranslation` to `django-translated-fields`. And also found your issue on `django-translated-fields` repository on Github.

Unfortunately i'm not able to fully understand what is the problem you have.
I think that your problem can be subdivided into two independent ones.

1. Migration not working for django-translated-fields
2. Dynamic creation of translated fields in forms.

So maybe we can start with the migration.
What do you mean when you say migration is not working. Can you show me the errors?

Comment: I moved `city` from `SiteProfile` to `User`. The problem was in calling `ModelForm` without hard-coding `city_en` and `city_he`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all field of model in ModelForm dynamically whenever you change model, you can check this. (I have tried, it works.)

in **forms.py**

```
def admin_list_display(model_name):
    list = [field.name for field in model_name._meta.get_fields()]
    return list

class EpisodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        fields = admin_list_display(Episode)
```

**----- Big Warning-------**

it will show error with non editable fields like (if you can change function to exclude these type of fields please edit the answer.):

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'created_at' cannot be specified for Episode model form as it is a non-editable field
```

if you remove `auto_now_add=True` from this, it will work.

**Note**

it will create drop down list for ForiegnKeyField of all options.

Comment: The `fields` attribute in `class Meta` in my form is correct. But the problem is that these fields (the fields I want to define dynamically) are not in the `SpeedyMatchSiteProfile` model (they are in another model).